# Do variables on namespaces always have default values?

Tags: c++, namespaces, default-value

Here's the code in question:

```
#ifndef _ALTERFPS_H
#define _ALTERFPS_H

#include "HUDLuaFunctions.h"
#include "AlterFPSNodes.h"

namespace AlterFPS
{
    namespace Globals
    {
        static bool teamAwareness;
        static int teams[] = {0, 0};

        static bool getAwareness() {
            return teamAwareness;    
        }

        static void setAwareness(bool aware) {
            teamAwareness = aware;
        }
    }
}

#endif
```

The problem is teamAwareness is always false.

I breakpoint the getter and the setter (I have them there for debug purposes, i know this isn't Java) and find that the setter does set the variable to true but a subsequent call to getAwareness shows that teamAwareness is false (No setAwareness calls in between)... How can this be possible? How do i fix it?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. I get `true` or `false` from the getter depending on what I've given the setter.

Comment: I am using this code inside an engine i don't know much about? Is there any way to know of said engine is messing up my code somehow? In other words, how can i breakpoint whenever that variable changes? The only references to teamAwareness are get and set, which is exactly what i want.

Comment: @Drknezz: maybe the problem is not in the above code but in the way you use it. The code looks ok to me, and chrisaycock seems to have tested it...

Comment: How many places is this header file included?  Each place will have its own copy of a variable called `teamAwareness` since you're declaring it  as `static`

Comment: @NiallC. I'm using it on 2 places, and those subsequent calls generate from each place, that's the root of the problem!. How can i make it so those variables are shared for all the AlterFPS::Global namespace usages?

Comment: @Drknezz: Change the `static` to `extern` in the header files, then define the variables in a .cpp file: `namespace AlterFPS { namespace Global { bool teamAwareness; int teams[] = {0, 0}; } }`

Comment: @NiallC. I've applied your fix but somehow i am getting weird redefinition errors on two source files that include Game.h (That also includes this header file) and this file... how can that be? Isn't it Header-guarded?

Comment: http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article1798.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables with static lifetime are always zero-initialized. Those include:

- Namespace variables (including the global namespace), be it static or not.
- Local static variables.
- Member static variables.

Zero-initialization, making it simple, means:

- If it is of numeric type: 0
- If it is bool: false
- If it is pointer: NULL
- If it is enum: 0 cast to the enum type
- If it is of class type: default constructed.

But your problem is not related to that, it is because your variable is declared `static` and it is in a header file, so each compilation unit (.cpp file) that includes it actually sees it's own instance of the variable. If you change it from one .cpp file you will not see the change from another.

What you want to do is declare the variable `extern` in the .h file and then define it normally (without modifier) in any .cpp file:

```
//.h file
namespace Globals
{
    extern bool teamAwareness; 

    inline void setAwareness(bool aware) {
        teamAwareness = aware;
    }
}

//.cpp file
namespace Globals
{
    bool teamAwareness; 
}
```

BTW, the function is better declared `inline`.